# Unable to access url due to code in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to access a url but not able to do so due to this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,20})/(.*)/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=$1&pram1=$2&pram2=$3 [L]
```

I am trying to access a specific folder and in order to access it I wrote the following code in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,20})/(.*)/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=$1&pram1=$2&pram2=$3 [L]
```

But still I am not able to access the files under `test` directory. Please let me know what am I missing in it?

Comment: Which file you want to access in test directory, is it index.php? or you are doing like `test/url/file/id` to access the file.

Comment: No I am just trying to access test/test.php